# How to modify Firebase remote config parameters from Android App

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I could **get** the Firebase remote config parameter from my app using below code.

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getContext());

firebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings configSettings = new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder().build();
firebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettings(configSettings);

Map<String, Object> defaultSettings = new HashMap();
firebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaults(defaultSettings);

firebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(0)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Task<Void> task) {
                // Doing my app activities
            }
        });
```

Is there a way to **set/modify** the parameter from Android App ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change them from the client side, the purpose of Remote Config is to fetch data from the service and update your UI or services accordingly to them.

You can use Firestore or Firebase Realtime Database if you need to set values and request them.

Comment: Technically speaking you could call the [Remote Config REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-rest) from the Android app. But as Gastón says, that is a bad idea as it'd open you up to abuse. Besides: if the Android app knows what change needs to be made, it could just make that change - without calling Remote Config to begin with.